# No module named bs4 when using cx-freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert my python script in to standalone executable for Windows using [cx-freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). For that I just typed this command `cxfreeze PlaylistDownloader.py` (PlaylistDownloader.py is my script file) then it did the following things.

```
PS C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader> cxfreeze PlaylistDownloader.py
creating directory C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist
\PlaylistDownloader.exe
copying C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.dll -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\python27.dll
writing zip file C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\PlaylistDownloader.exe

  Name                      File
  ----                      ----
m BrowserHelp               BrowserHelp.py
m StringIO
m UserDict
m _LWPCookieJar             C:\Python27\lib\_LWPCookieJar.py
m _MozillaCookieJar         C:\Python27\lib\_MozillaCookieJar.py
m __builtin__
m __future__                C:\Python27\lib\__future__.py
m __main__                  PlaylistDownloader.py
m _abcoll
m _bisect
m _codecs
m _codecs_cn
m _codecs_hk
m _codecs_iso2022
m _codecs_jp
m _codecs_kr
m _codecs_tw
m _collections
m _ctypes                   C:\Python27\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
m _functools
m _hashlib                  C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
m _heapq
m _io
m _json
m _locale
m _md5
m _multibytecodec
m _random
m _sha
m _sha256
m _sha512
m _socket                   C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd
m _sre
m _ssl                      C:\Python27\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
m _strptime                 C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py
m _struct
m _subprocess
m _threading_local          C:\Python27\lib\_threading_local.py
m _warnings
m _weakref
m _weakrefset
m _winreg
m abc
m array
m atexit                    C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py
m base64
m bdb                       C:\Python27\lib\bdb.py
m binascii
m bisect                    C:\Python27\lib\bisect.py
m bz2                       C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd
m cPickle
m cStringIO
m calendar                  C:\Python27\lib\calendar.py
m cmd                       C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py
m codecs
m collections               C:\Python27\lib\collections.py
m cookielib                 C:\Python27\lib\cookielib.py
m copy
m copy_reg
P ctypes                    C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py
m ctypes._endian            C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\_endian.py
P ctypes.macholib           C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\macholib\__init__.py
m ctypes.macholib.dyld      C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\macholib\dyld.py
m ctypes.macholib.dylib     C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\macholib\dylib.py
m ctypes.macholib.framework C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\macholib\framework.py
m ctypes.util               C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\util.py
m ctypes.wintypes           C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\wintypes.py
m cx_Freeze__init__         C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py
m datetime
m decimal                   C:\Python27\lib\decimal.py
m difflib                   C:\Python27\lib\difflib.py
m dis                       C:\Python27\lib\dis.py
P distutils                 C:\Python27\lib\distutils\__init__.py
m distutils.errors          C:\Python27\lib\distutils\errors.py
m distutils.log             C:\Python27\lib\distutils\log.py
m distutils.spawn           C:\Python27\lib\distutils\spawn.py
m doctest                   C:\Python27\lib\doctest.py
m dummy_thread              C:\Python27\lib\dummy_thread.py
m dummy_threading           C:\Python27\lib\dummy_threading.py
P email                     C:\Python27\lib\email\__init__.py
m email._parseaddr          C:\Python27\lib\email\_parseaddr.py
m email.base64mime          C:\Python27\lib\email\base64mime.py
m email.charset             C:\Python27\lib\email\charset.py
m email.encoders            C:\Python27\lib\email\encoders.py
m email.errors              C:\Python27\lib\email\errors.py
m email.feedparser          C:\Python27\lib\email\feedparser.py
m email.generator           C:\Python27\lib\email\generator.py
m email.header              C:\Python27\lib\email\header.py
m email.iterators           C:\Python27\lib\email\iterators.py
m email.message             C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py
P email.mime                C:\Python27\lib\email\mime\__init__.py
m email.parser              C:\Python27\lib\email\parser.py
m email.quoprimime          C:\Python27\lib\email\quoprimime.py
m email.utils               C:\Python27\lib\email\utils.py
P encodings
m encodings.aliases
m encodings.ascii
m encodings.base64_codec
m encodings.big5
m encodings.big5hkscs
m encodings.bz2_codec
m encodings.charmap
m encodings.cp037
m encodings.cp1006
m encodings.cp1026
m encodings.cp1140
m encodings.cp1250
m encodings.cp1251
m encodings.cp1252
m encodings.cp1253
m encodings.cp1254
m encodings.cp1255
m encodings.cp1256
m encodings.cp1257
m encodings.cp1258
m encodings.cp424
m encodings.cp437
m encodings.cp500
m encodings.cp720
m encodings.cp737
m encodings.cp775
m encodings.cp850
m encodings.cp852
m encodings.cp855
m encodings.cp856
m encodings.cp857
m encodings.cp858
m encodings.cp860
m encodings.cp861
m encodings.cp862
m encodings.cp863
m encodings.cp864
m encodings.cp865
m encodings.cp866
m encodings.cp869
m encodings.cp874
m encodings.cp875
m encodings.cp932
m encodings.cp949
m encodings.cp950
m encodings.euc_jis_2004
m encodings.euc_jisx0213
m encodings.euc_jp
m encodings.euc_kr
m encodings.gb18030
m encodings.gb2312
m encodings.gbk
m encodings.hex_codec
m encodings.hp_roman8
m encodings.hz
m encodings.idna
m encodings.iso2022_jp
m encodings.iso2022_jp_1
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2
m encodings.iso2022_jp_2004
m encodings.iso2022_jp_3
m encodings.iso2022_jp_ext
m encodings.iso2022_kr
m encodings.iso8859_1
m encodings.iso8859_10
m encodings.iso8859_11
m encodings.iso8859_13
m encodings.iso8859_14
m encodings.iso8859_15
m encodings.iso8859_16
m encodings.iso8859_2
m encodings.iso8859_3
m encodings.iso8859_4
m encodings.iso8859_5
m encodings.iso8859_6
m encodings.iso8859_7
m encodings.iso8859_8
m encodings.iso8859_9
m encodings.johab
m encodings.koi8_r
m encodings.koi8_u
m encodings.latin_1
m encodings.mac_arabic
m encodings.mac_centeuro
m encodings.mac_croatian
m encodings.mac_cyrillic
m encodings.mac_farsi
m encodings.mac_greek
m encodings.mac_iceland
m encodings.mac_latin2
m encodings.mac_roman
m encodings.mac_romanian
m encodings.mac_turkish
m encodings.mbcs
m encodings.palmos
m encodings.ptcp154
m encodings.punycode
m encodings.quopri_codec
m encodings.raw_unicode_escape
m encodings.rot_13
m encodings.shift_jis
m encodings.shift_jis_2004
m encodings.shift_jisx0213
m encodings.string_escape
m encodings.tis_620
m encodings.undefined
m encodings.unicode_escape
m encodings.unicode_internal
m encodings.utf_16
m encodings.utf_16_be
m encodings.utf_16_le
m encodings.utf_32
m encodings.utf_32_be
m encodings.utf_32_le
m encodings.utf_7
m encodings.utf_8
m encodings.utf_8_sig
m encodings.uu_codec
m encodings.zlib_codec
m errno
m exceptions
m fnmatch                   C:\Python27\lib\fnmatch.py
m ftplib                    C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py
m functools                 C:\Python27\lib\functools.py
m gc
m genericpath
m getopt                    C:\Python27\lib\getopt.py
m getpass                   C:\Python27\lib\getpass.py
m gettext                   C:\Python27\lib\gettext.py
m glob                      C:\Python27\lib\glob.py
m gzip                      C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py
m hashlib                   C:\Python27\lib\hashlib.py
m heapq                     C:\Python27\lib\heapq.py
m hmac                      C:\Python27\lib\hmac.py
m httplib                   C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py
m imp
m inspect                   C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py
m io                        C:\Python27\lib\io.py
m itertools
P json                      C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py
m json.decoder              C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py
m json.encoder              C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py
m json.scanner              C:\Python27\lib\json\scanner.py
m keyword                   C:\Python27\lib\keyword.py
m linecache
m locale                    C:\Python27\lib\locale.py
P logging                   C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py
m logging.handlers          C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py
m marshal
m math
m mimetools                 C:\Python27\lib\mimetools.py
m mimetypes                 C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py
m msvcrt
m new                       C:\Python27\lib\new.py
m nt
m ntpath
m nturl2path                C:\Python27\lib\nturl2path.py
m numbers                   C:\Python27\lib\numbers.py
m opcode                    C:\Python27\lib\opcode.py
m operator
m optparse                  C:\Python27\lib\optparse.py
m os
m pdb                       C:\Python27\lib\pdb.py
m pickle                    C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py
m platform                  C:\Python27\lib\platform.py
m plistlib                  C:\Python27\lib\plistlib.py
m posixpath
m pprint                    C:\Python27\lib\pprint.py
m py_compile                C:\Python27\lib\py_compile.py
m pyexpat                   C:\Python27\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
P pyreadline                C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\__init__.py
P pyreadline.clipboard      C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\__init__.py
m pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\ironpython_clipboard.py
m pyreadline.clipboard.no_clipboard C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\no_clipboard.py
m pyreadline.clipboard.win32_clipboard C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\clipboard\win32_clipboard.py
P pyreadline.console        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\__init__.py
m pyreadline.console.ansi   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ansi.py
m pyreadline.console.console C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\console.py
m pyreadline.console.event  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\event.py
m pyreadline.console.ironpython_console C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\console\ironpython_console.py
m pyreadline.error          C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\error.py
P pyreadline.keysyms        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\__init__.py
m pyreadline.keysyms.common C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\common.py
m pyreadline.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\ironpython_keysyms.py
m pyreadline.keysyms.keysyms C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\keysyms.py
m pyreadline.keysyms.winconstants C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\keysyms\winconstants.py
P pyreadline.lineeditor     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\__init__.py
m pyreadline.lineeditor.history C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py
m pyreadline.lineeditor.lineobj C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\lineobj.py
m pyreadline.lineeditor.wordmatcher C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\wordmatcher.py
m pyreadline.logger         C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\logger.py
P pyreadline.modes          C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\__init__.py
m pyreadline.modes.basemode C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py
m pyreadline.modes.emacs    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py
m pyreadline.modes.notemacs C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\notemacs.py
m pyreadline.modes.vi       C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\vi.py
m pyreadline.release        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\release.py
m pyreadline.rlmain         C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py
m pyreadline.unicode_helper C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\unicode_helper.py
m pywintypes                C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\pywintypes27.dll
m quopri
m random                    C:\Python27\lib\random.py
m re                        C:\Python27\lib\re.py
m readline                  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\readline.py
m repr
m rfc822                    C:\Python27\lib\rfc822.py
m select                    C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd
P selenium                  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py
P selenium.common           C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\common\__init__.py
m selenium.common.exceptions C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\common\exceptions.py
m selenium.selenium         C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\selenium.py
P selenium.webdriver        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py
P selenium.webdriver.chrome C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.chrome.options C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\options.py
m selenium.webdriver.chrome.service C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py
m selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py
P selenium.webdriver.common C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.alert C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\alert.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.by C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\by.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\desired_capabil
ities.py
P selenium.webdriver.common.html5 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\html5\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.html5.application_cache C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\html5\applic
ation_cache.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.keys C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\keys.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.proxy C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\proxy.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\touch_actions.py
m selenium.webdriver.common.utils C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py
P selenium.webdriver.firefox C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.firefox.extension_connection C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_con
nection.py
m selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py
m selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py

m selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py
P selenium.webdriver.ie     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.ie.service C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\service.py
m selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py
P selenium.webdriver.opera  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\opera\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.opera.service C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\opera\service.py
m selenium.webdriver.opera.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\opera\webdriver.py
P selenium.webdriver.phantomjs C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py
m selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py
P selenium.webdriver.remote C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\__init__.py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.command C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\command.py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.
py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.utils C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\utils.py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py
m selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py
m sets                      C:\Python27\lib\sets.py
m shlex                     C:\Python27\lib\shlex.py
m shutil                    C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py
m signal
P simplejson                C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py
m simplejson._speedups      C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\_speedups.pyd
m simplejson.decoder        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py
m simplejson.encoder        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py
m simplejson.ordered_dict   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\ordered_dict.py
m simplejson.scanner        C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py
m smtplib                   C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py
m socket                    C:\Python27\lib\socket.py
m sre_compile               C:\Python27\lib\sre_compile.py
m sre_constants             C:\Python27\lib\sre_constants.py
m sre_parse                 C:\Python27\lib\sre_parse.py
m ssl                       C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py
m stat
m string
m stringprep
m strop
m struct
m subprocess                C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py
m sys
m tarfile                   C:\Python27\lib\tarfile.py
m tempfile                  C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py
m textwrap                  C:\Python27\lib\textwrap.py
m thread
m threading                 C:\Python27\lib\threading.py
m time
m token                     C:\Python27\lib\token.py
m tokenize                  C:\Python27\lib\tokenize.py
m traceback
m types
m unicodedata               C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
P unittest                  C:\Python27\lib\unittest\__init__.py
m unittest.case             C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py
m unittest.loader           C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py
m unittest.main             C:\Python27\lib\unittest\main.py
m unittest.result           C:\Python27\lib\unittest\result.py
m unittest.runner           C:\Python27\lib\unittest\runner.py
m unittest.signals          C:\Python27\lib\unittest\signals.py
m unittest.suite            C:\Python27\lib\unittest\suite.py
m unittest.util             C:\Python27\lib\unittest\util.py
m urllib                    C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py
m urllib2                   C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py
m urlparse                  C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py
m uu                        C:\Python27\lib\uu.py
m warnings
m weakref
m webbrowser                C:\Python27\lib\webbrowser.py
m win32api                  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd
m win32con                  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32con.py
m win32evtlog               C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32evtlog.pyd
m win32evtlogutil           C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32evtlogutil.py
m win32pipe                 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pipe.pyd
m winerror                  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\winerror.py
P xml                       C:\Python27\lib\xml\__init__.py
P xml.dom                   C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\__init__.py
m xml.dom.NodeFilter        C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\NodeFilter.py
m xml.dom.domreg            C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\domreg.py
m xml.dom.expatbuilder      C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py
m xml.dom.minicompat        C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minicompat.py
m xml.dom.minidom           C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py
m xml.dom.pulldom           C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\pulldom.py
m xml.dom.xmlbuilder        C:\Python27\lib\xml\dom\xmlbuilder.py
P xml.parsers               C:\Python27\lib\xml\parsers\__init__.py
m xml.parsers.expat         C:\Python27\lib\xml\parsers\expat.py
P xml.sax                   C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\__init__.py
m xml.sax._exceptions       C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\_exceptions.py
m xml.sax.expatreader       C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py
m xml.sax.handler           C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\handler.py
m xml.sax.saxutils          C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\saxutils.py
m xml.sax.xmlreader         C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py
m zipfile                   C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py
m zipimport
m zlib

Missing modules:
? IronPythonConsole imported from pyreadline.console.ironpython_console
? System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard imported from pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard
? bs4 imported from __main__
? clr imported from pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard
? http.client imported from selenium.selenium
? startup imported from pyreadline.keysyms.common
? urllib.parse imported from selenium.selenium
? winreg imported from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary

copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\_ctypes.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\_hashlib.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_socket.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\_socket.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\_ssl.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\_ssl.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\bz2.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\bz2.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\pyexpat.pyd
copying C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\pywintypes27.dll -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\pywintypes27.dll
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\select.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\select.pyd
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\_speedups.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\si
mplejson._speedups.pyd
copying C:\Python27\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\unicodedata.pyd
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\win32api
.pyd
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32evtlog.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\win32
evtlog.pyd
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32pipe.pyd -> C:\Users\BK\Desktop\#YoutubePlayListDownloader\dist\win32pi
pe.pyd
```

When all this things were done it created a folder name **dist** in that I found an exe file with the name of my script file. When I open that exe file it shows the following message in cmd.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "PlaylistDownloader.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Can anyone guide on how do this properly.

Comment: Try with `--include-modules bs4` option.  http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption--include-modules

Comment: That won't do it - `bs4` is already listed under 'missing modules', so it knows it needs it, it just can't find it. Where is it installed? cx_Freeze sometimes has trouble with modules installed in .egg directories.

Comment: @ThomasK how can I find where bs4 was installed

Comment: `import bs4; print bs4` should show you a filename.

Comment: @ThomasK it shows this `<module 'bs4' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.2.1-py2.7.egg\bs4\__init__.pyc'>`

Comment: Can you try moving/copying the bs4 directory up a level into site-packages? The .egg directory might be causing a problem.

Comment: But `beautifulsoup4-4.2.1-py2.7.egg` is not a directory its a EGG file type. I think its some kind of archive file.

Comment: @macdonjo No, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late, but re-install bs4 through pip, or  --always-unzip with easy_install.