# Extract java script from html document using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract java script from `google.com` using regular expression.

**Program**

```
import urllib
import re
gdoc = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
scriptlis = re.findall(r'<script>(.*?)</script>', gdoc)
print scriptlis
```

**Output:**

```
['']
```

Can any one tell me how to extract java script from html doc by using regular expression only.

Comment: @rid yes I am asking why its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
import urllib
import re
gdoc = urllib.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
scriptlis = re.findall('(?si)<script>(.*?)</script>', gdoc)
print scriptlis
```

The key here is `(?si)`.  The "s" sets the "dotall" flag (same as `re.DOTALL`), which makes Regex match over newlines.  That was actually the root of your problem.  The scripts on google.com span multiple lines, so Regex can't match them unless you tell it to include newlines in `(.*?)`.

The "i" sets the "ignorcase" flag (same as `re.IGNORECASE`), which allows it to match anything that can be JavaScript.  Now, this isn't entirely necessary because Google codes pretty well.  But, if you had poor code that did stuff similar to `<SCRIPT>...</SCRIPT>`, you will need this flag.

Comment: +1 for working .. could you elaborate on the `(?si)` part more

Comment: I don't know which one is correct but when I compare your answer with @Antti Haapala answer it is not equal
`re.findall('(?si)<script>(.*?)</script>', gdoc) == re.findall(r'<script\s*([^>]*)\s*>(.*?)</script', gdoc, re.I|re.S)`
Output: False

Comment: @woofmeow - There ya go.

Comment: @iCodez i googled it in the mean time ... but thanks .. learnt something (new lol) today :)

Comment: That's because his is getting attributes too.  I didn't think you wanted this based off of the sample code you gave.  If you do, this should work `'(?si)<script.*?>(.*?)</script>'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an issue with third party libraries, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) combined with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes for a great combination:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
p = bs(r.content)
p.find_all('script')
```

Comment: I am having some issue with [BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509612/no-module-named-bs4-when-using-cx-freeze). That's why only I want to use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably could try to do is

```
scriptlis = re.findall(r'<script\s*([^>]*)\s*>(.*?)</script', gdoc, re.I|re.S)
```

Because most script tags are of type:

```
<script language="javascript" src="foo"></script>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript">alert("foo")</script>
```

and some even are `<SCRIPT></SCRIPT>`

Neither of which match your regex. My regex would grab attributes in group 1, and the possible inline code in group 2. And also all tags within HTML comments. But it is about the best possible without BeautifulSoup et al

Comment: You mean `re.findall(r'<script\b\s*([^>]*)>(.*?)</script>', gdoc)`.

Comment: not working `scriptlis = re.findall(r'<script\b\s*([^>]*)>(.*?)</script>',gdoc)` Output: `[('', '')]`

Comment: I don't know which one is correct but when I compare your answer with @iCodez answer it is not equal
`re.findall('(?si)<script>(.*?)</script>', gdoc) == re.findall(r'<script\s*([^>]*)\s*>(.*?)</script', gdoc, re.I|re.S)`
Output: False

Comment: ofc not, because my script will fetch the attributes too, and not only inline scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the text between `<script>` and `</script>` is several lines, so you could try something like this:

```
rg = re.compile('<script>(.*)</script>', re.DOTALL)
result = re.findall(rg, gdoc)
```

Comment: You want it nongreedy `re.compile('<script>(.*?)</script>', re.DOTALL)`