# Get data from javascript to python using scrapy python

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, web-crawler

How to get the data from javascript content using scrapy python ? The javascript look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ad_reply_url = "http://www2.mudah.my/ar/send/0?ca=3_s&id=49825097&l=0";
  var mcvl = "";
  var images = [
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/133608119523265.jpg', 
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/135608116569903.jpg', 
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/137608113616541.jpg', 
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/139608119186498.jpg'
  ];
 var thumbnails = [
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/133608119523265.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/135608116569903.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/137608113616541.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/139608119186498.jpg'
 ];</script>
```

So, what I want is. I want the data from var images and print that data like this

```
['http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/133608119523265.jpg','http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/135608116569903.jpg', 'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/137608113616541.jpg','http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/139608119186498.jpg' ];
```

Can anyone help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using Scrapy Python, just regular Python.
It is pretty straightforward though:

Code Sample:

```
import ast
import re

page_source = '''
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ad_reply_url = "http://www2.mudah.my/ar/send/0?ca=3_s&id=49825097&l=0";
  var mcvl = "";
  var images = [
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/133608119523265.jpg',
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/135608116569903.jpg',
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/137608113616541.jpg',
     'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/139608119186498.jpg'
  ];
 var thumbnails = [
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/133608119523265.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/135608116569903.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/137608113616541.jpg',
    'http://img.rnudah.com/thumbs/13/139608119186498.jpg'
 ];</script>
'''

variables = re.findall('(?si)var(.*?);', page_source)

var_collection = {}
for var in variables:
    var = var.strip()
    var_key = var.split(' = ')[0]
    var_value = ast.literal_eval(var.split(' = ')[1])
    var_collection.update({var_key: var_value})

print(var_collection['images'])
```

Output:

```
['http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/133608119523265.jpg', 'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/135608116569903.jpg', 'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/137608113616541.jpg', 'http://img.rnudah.com/images/13/139608119186498.jpg']
```

Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108644/295246

Comment: okay .. thanks give me a hint .. just now I was trying to manipulate your code and now  I got what I want ... thanks man ! :)

Comment: @shahril Glad it helped. Feel free to upvote or accept this answer as your solution, to your discretion. Thanks!

Comment: @Ale Pleasure is mine! Seems this question doesn't come up too often :)